# Combine multiple matches across multiple lines into a single match

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match a continuous content spanning multiple lines which are marked by a marker `>`.
Example:

```
Some text      <- is not matched
Another Text   <- also ignored
> This should be included
> And also this
> This as well
But not this   <- ignored
```

The match should return only this (as full match or a single capturing group):

```
This should be included
And also this
This as well
```

My current approach is this regex (JavaScript):

```regex
/(?:(?<=^> ).+\n)+/gm
```

It does correctly captures the content I need but it does not combine three matched lines into a single match (so it produces **three** separate matches instead of **one**).

Why doesn't it group three non-capturing group matches into one?
Is it even possible to accomplish this task with JavaScript regex only?

Comment: Single capture group cannot exclude character from inside a match.

Comment: You can use something like `str = str.match(/(?:\n> .*)+/g)[0].replace(/^\n|> /g, '')`

Answer (score 1):

Using your pattern you will get 3 matches instead of 1 match because when moving to the next line, this assertion `(?<=^> )` is not true so the engine will move forward looking for the next possible match.

One option to get your result is to use a pattern to first get all the matches, and then perform a second replacement for all the `>`  parts.

```
^> .+(?:\r?\n>.*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rIHHbB/1)

```js
const regex = /^> .+(?:\r?\n> .+)*/gm;
const str = `Some text
Another Text
> This should be included
> And also this
> This as well
But not this`;

let result = str.match(regex)[0].replace(/^> /gm, "");
console.log(result);
```